# What is the sequence of events in which nodes in the DOM change?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

TL;DR:

Entering a carriage return <kbd>↵</kbd> between two characters and thus causing a new `LI` node to be automatically generated, what events occurred in the DOM during this entire process, and what is the order?

Is my inference below correct? Of course, you can also directly elucidate yours without having to look at a lot of my words, thank you very much!

---

---

I saw a [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#Mutation_Observer_customize_resize_event_listener_demo) when I reading and learning [Mutation Observer at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and simplified it as follows:

```
const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver

const list = document.querySelector(`ol`);

const config = {
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => 
  console.log(mutations)
)
observer.observe(list, config)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Mutation Observer & customize resize event listener & demo</title>
  <style>
    ol {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      max-width: 20rem;
      border: 1px solid crimson;
      resize: both;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Mutation Observer & customize resize event listener & demo</h1>
    <strong>Please open the console of your own browser.</strong> (Because if using the too simple console in the Code Snippet on Stack Overflow, then your browser will be hanged for a few seconds when you inputting characters, since it is going to dump and display massive amounts of data.)
  </section>
  <section>
    <ol contenteditable>
      <li>a</li>
    </ol>
  </section>

  <script>
    const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver

    const list = document.querySelector(`ol`);
    // options
    const config = {
      characterData: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    }
    // instance
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations =>
      console.log(mutations)
    )
    observer.observe(list, config)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I did two operations (which will be mentioned below) on this adapted demo and observed the console, but I am not quite sure about **the specific events (what happen and what is the sequence?)** in each `MutationRecord`, only to speculate in reverse what they are (also be mentioned below).

The two operations and the text before and after each operation are:

[image: Operation 0]
 1. Enter a character "b" after the character "a";
 [image: Operation 1]
 2. Enter a carriage return <kbd>↵</kbd> between the characters "a" and "b".
 [image: Operation 2]

And all the output in the console:
 [image: console]

---

The following is my **speculation** about event procedures for each `MutationRecord`, with symbol annotations.

#### The detailed version

```html
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap">
// line 1: "a"

// [Operation 1] Enter a character "b" after the character "a":

// [Console output]
[MutationRecord]

0: MutationRecord {type: "characterData", target: text, …}
// OL > LI#1 > #text"a"(+)"b"
// list at line 1 added a character "b".


// line 1: "ab"

// [Operation 2] Enter a carriage return `↵` between the characters "a" and "b":

// [Console output]
Array(5) [MutationRecord, MutationRecord, MutationRecord, MutationRecord, MutationRecord]

0: MutationRecord {type: "childList", target: li, addedNodes: NodeList(1), removedNodes: NodeList(0), previousSibling: null, nextSibling: text, …}
// OL > LI#1 > (-+)#text"a"
// `↵` causes the text node containing the character "a" be split off from the li node transiently and then be prepended back to its original resident li node immediately.

1: MutationRecord {type: "characterData", target: text, addedNodes: NodeList(0), removedNodes: NodeList(0), previousSibling: null, nextSibling: null, …}
// OL > LI#1 > #text(-+)"b"
// `↵` causes the character "b" be split off from its owner text node transiently and then be prepended back to its original resident text node immediately.

2: MutationRecord {type: "childList", target: ol, addedNodes: NodeList(1), removedNodes: NodeList(0), previousSibling: li, nextSibling: text, …}
// OL > (+)LI#2
// A new li node appears (for holding the text node which contains the character "b" at soon) and is appended to the end inside the ol node.

3: MutationRecord {type: "childList", target: li, addedNodes: NodeList(0), removedNodes: NodeList(1), previousSibling: text, …}
// OL > LI#1 > (-)#text"b"
// The last child of the first li node is moved out — the text node containing the character "b" is detached from the first li node.

4: MutationRecord {type: "childList", target: li, addedNodes: NodeList(1), removedNodes: NodeList(0), previousSibling: null, …}
// OL > LI#2 > (+)#text"b"
// The text node containing the character "b" is appended to the second li node.


// line 1: "a"
// line 2: "b"
</pre>
```

#### The brief version

```
// line 1: "a"

// Enter a character "b" after the character "a".
// The mutation is equivalent to:

    OL > LI#1 > #text"a"(+)"b"


// line 1: "ab"

// Enter a carriage return `↵` between the characters "a" and "b".
// The mutations are equivalent to:

    OL >    LI#1 > (-+)#text    "a"
    OL >    LI#1 >     #text(-+)"b"
    OL > (+)LI#2
    OL >    LI#1 >  (-)#text    "b"
    OL >    LI#2 >  (+)#text    "b"


// line 1: "a"
// line 2: "b"
```

Comment: Seems correct, but I wouldn't rely on this sequence as it may be implementation-specific and subject to change without notice - if it's not described in some DOM specification. BTW `characterDataOldValue: true` in the options could be helpful for such investigations.